# mysql_query("SELECT...") returns row of NULL values for nonexistent primary key value, rendering (mysql_num_rows > 0) check useless

Tags: php, mysql, null, row

i'm very new to using mysql with php, and here's what i found online to retrieve my results:

```
$con = mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Cannot connect to the database");
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ID=5";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0 ) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // inform user
}
mysql_close($con);
```

`ID` is my table's autogenerated non-null primary key. right now, i have 20 records in my table. if i enter an `ID` value corresponding to any of these existing records, everything goes well and works as intended.

however, if i enter an `ID` value of, say, 54 or anything that doesn't correspond to any of my existing 20 records (meaning no row with such an `ID` exists), i expect `$num <= 0` and my conditional statement will go to the `else` block. but i found out that wasn't the case - it still goes to the `TRUE` branch and proceeds to `// do stuff` block, so i ran the query on phpmyadmin and found out that i'm getting exactly 1 row with `NULL` in all of the fields. that's why `$num` was returning `1` which is `>0`.

questions:

1. how do i properly go about checking for nonexistent rows? so that the rest of my script will only run if i actually get a row that contains data.
2. i found `mysql_store_result` and `mysql_free_result` while researching this online but there's not enough info to make them work properly. like where in my code do i place them, how come i can do what i need to do right now in php even without them, etc?
3. any "best practice" stuff i'm missing here when dealing with mysql databases in php?
4. when i have to call several sql statements, what i do is cycle through the `$query`-`$result`-`$num` process before i `mysql_close` my connection. is that "best practice"?

thank so much, guys, you're all amazing.

**UPDATE:** Including whole query

```
SELECT Dyna, 
       Floater, 
       Can.Label as CanLabel, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Vanity.Name SEPARATOR ', ') as VanityName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Univ SEPARATOR ', ') as Univ, 
       ShopDate, 
       ManuDate, 
       FlipTran, 
       Remarks, 
       Bib, 
       Abbrev, 
       ShopChar, 
       Comment, 
       Value, 
       ERUSD 
       FROM 
       (Vanity INNER JOIN ((Vanity INNER JOIN Shoppy ON Vanity.VanityID = Shoppy.VanityID) INNER JOIN ShoppyVanity ON Shoppy.ID = ShoppyVanity.ID) ON Vanity.MethodID = ShoppyVanity.MethodID) INNER JOIN UAC ON (Shoppy.VanityID = UAC.VanityID) AND (Vanity.VanityID = UAC.VanityID) 
        WHERE (((Shoppy.ID)=5))
```

Comment: I don't know much about PHP and the `mysql_numrows` function that you use, but I can assure you that ANY DBMS where you do `select ... from where ID=5` and there are no records with ID 5 still yields a result, is a very strange one. Are you sure that is your whole query? Are you doing some kind of left join to other table maybe?

Comment: know what i am! wow, didn't even think that'd be the case. my `SELECT` has a number of `INNER JOIN`s, plus a couple of `GROUP_CONCAT`s. if that's what's giving me the row of `NULL` values, how do i check for this then, just check for all values through the row? thanks, @Icarus

Comment: INNER JOINS won't yield a result either if you are joining with the ID field of the table you say doesn't have a record with ID 5. Post the whole query if you can.

Comment: here goes: `SELECT Dyna, Floater, Can.Label as CanLabel, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Vanity.Name SEPARATOR ', ') as VanityName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Univ SEPARATOR ', ') as Univ, ShopDate, ManuDate, FlipTran, Remarks, Bib, Abbrev, ShopChar, Comment, Value, ERUSD FROM (Vanity INNER JOIN ((Vanity INNER JOIN Shoppy ON Vanity.VanityID = Shoppy.VanityID) INNER JOIN ShoppyVanity ON Shoppy.ID = ShoppyVanity.ID) ON Vanity.MethodID = ShoppyVanity.MethodID) INNER JOIN UAC ON (Shoppy.VanityID = UAC.VanityID) AND (Vanity.VanityID = UAC.VanityID) WHERE (((Shoppy.ID)=5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use group aggregate functions such as `GROUP_CONCAT` MySQL will create a group out of your whole result set. If there are no results, it will run them on `NULL` values instead, resulting in an empty row. Try adding this to the very end of your query to get rid of rows that don't have valid data in them:

`HAVING VanityName IS NOT NULL`

Comment: one last question: should i also add `Unit` to `VanityName` in the `HAVING ... IS NOT NULL` phrase because i `GROUP_CONCAT`ed on `Unit`? if so, how will i do this? thanks

Comment: @Ana: You could use `HAVING VanityName IS NOT NULL AND Univ IS NOT NULL` but it's not necessary. If there are no rows, both will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Change it to

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: oh wow thanks for spotting that. however, still get the row of `NULL`s. but yeap thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Dyna, 
       Floater, 
       Can.Label as CanLabel, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Vanity.Name SEPARATOR ', ') as VanityName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Univ SEPARATOR ', ') as Univ, 
       ShopDate, 
       ManuDate, 
       FlipTran, 
       Remarks, 
       Bib, 
       Abbrev, 
       ShopChar, 
       Comment, 
       Value, 
       ERUSD 
       FROM 
       Vanity INNER JOIN Shoppy ON (Vanity.VanityID = Shoppy.VanityID)
       INNER JOIN ShoppyVanity  ON (Shoppy.ID = ShoppyVanity.ID)
       INNER JOIN ShoppyVanity  ON (ShoppyVanity.MethodID=Vanity.MethodID) 
       INNER JOIN UAC           ON (Shoppy.VanityID = UAC.VanityID AND Vanity.VanityID =UAC.VanityID) 
       WHERE Shoppy.ID=5
```

Comment: although i already marked another answer right, i would love to know how this improves on my sql statement. thanks, much

Answer (score 0):

Use a different `mysql_*` function, such as `mysql_fetch_assoc`. If you read the manual, found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php, you will see that it returns `false` if there are no rows to fetch. Typically, you can make that call the conditional for a `while` loop, i.e.:

```
while( $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    // do something
}
```

This will loop until it has read the last row.

Comment: thanks much, tieson. you mean different from `mysql_query` right? is this "better practice"? do you have other "best practice"s that i can use? thanks again

Comment: No, this is called after your call to `mysql_query`. The examples on the manual page should be a good start for how to use it. As far as 'best practice' goes, you should start by using the _mysqli_ library or _PDO_, as both are much newer and provide better tools for querying your database.